# RaisePropertyChanged not working for updating UI in Droid

Tags: android, listview, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have List of items. When i delete item from collection then all working fine. But when add an item then getting update problem to UI in mvvm cross Droid. In WP and IOS it is working fine. When item get added then all data return from API and set to list property but then SET accessor of property get call, but RaisePropertyChanged not working that time because GET accessor not called. Since new added item not display in List. This is my Code :

ViewModel :

```
public ObservableCollection<AppointmentDto> Appointments
    {
        get
        {
            if (appointments == null)
                appointments = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentDto>();

            return (appointments);
        }
        set
        {
            appointments = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Appointments);               
        }


private async void doApptsFetchAsync(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var appts = await schedulingService.GetAppointmentsAsync(Id);
            if (appts != null)
            {                  

                Appointments = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentDto>(appts);                  
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Mvx.Resolve<IUserInteraction>().Alert(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I delete item then call same above method and its working fine, when initialize  Appointments property then SET and GET both accessors called. When add item then also call  same above method, in this time while initialize Appointments property it call only SET accessor not called GET accessor. Since no UI update with new added item.

I tried both List and ObservableCollection type for property but no luck.

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to enforce execution on the UI thread? `InvokeOnMainThread(() => Appointments = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentDto>(appts));`

Comment: Why are you overwriting the ObservableCollection every time?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe : I tried your solution but it dint work for me.

Comment: @Cheesebaron : Issue get resolved. when add new item I get response i.e newly added item, that response I add in my collection and now it update my UI.

Comment: @Cheesebaron : But Suppose I call API after adding item, same as I did above then why it is not update UI in droid only ? Is it Droid binding issue OR something else ?